# law of demeter and hashmap

Tags: oop

I have few questions.
First of all does code below violates law of Demeter?

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo","bar");
map.put("fooo","baaar");
map.keySet().iterator()
```

IMO code above violates law of Demeter because map type is Map and keySet() returns Set object. Both are different. I'm thinking about second property to hold only "keys" but is this right solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically that is a violation of the Law of Demeter when described in terms of methods. However, the way to fix it would be to here would be to *add an operation like "keysIterator" to the Map class*, and that might be a reasonable action, except that here **Map is not your code**.

The *purpose* of the Law of Demeter is to reduce coupling between **components of your application**. Changing how you use standard library objects does not affect that. Your proposed solution is wasteful of resources and has no particular benefit.

From another perspective, the keySet of a Map is really just a facet of the Map. You should think of it not so much as a third object (where LoD essentially says you shouldn't have more than two objects in any interaction) as a way of categorizing the operations that the Map provides.

---

Imagine a different scenario: suppose you have an **application class** like, say, a Category in an online store. It would be a *meaningful* LoD violation to have

```
category.itemsSet().iterator()
```

and this is something that you might want to refactor. Why? Because it constrains the Category class to implement a Set, even if the only operation that is actually needed is iteration (or, generally, fewer operations than the Set interface has), rather than having an implementation which only does the necessary work and can be revised or reimplemented more easily.

On the other hand, if the things you want to do to a Category cover all of the Set operations, then it's silly not to provide a `Category.itemsSet()` facet.

---

*Note: “Facet” here means an object which is in a 1:1 relationship to another object and is essentially a different view of “the same thing”, especially a narrower view. It is not an entirely standard term.*

Comment: well said. also you should not see the "law" as a law but more as a suggestion or guideline that may be broken when it makes sense (as Kevin laid out here).